# Laravel 7.1.x missing files: AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I just upgraded from Laravel 6.x to 7.1.x and now my application is messed up due to changes. One of which is the login authentication.

With the new Laravel 7.1.2, these files are gone.

1. use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
2. use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

If you are to check the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/), these files are missing as well. With that, may I know what files they are replaced with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

they are in the https://github.com/laravel/ui package. just install it and you're good to go.